# Есть ли событие перед submit'ом формы html?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp-net-core-mvc

У меня есть табличка, которую я генерирую с помощью `DataTable`, в ней которые поля - редактируются пользователем. Все это дело находится в теге `<form asp-page="MyPage">` вместе с кнопкной `<button type="submit">` которая **генерируется автоматически** фреймворком который я использую, поэтому повесить `id` и `on click` не получится.

Помимо этого, есть `<input asp-for="EditShopItemVM.JsonKeyValue">`, оно помечено как `[HiddenInput]`.

В js коде я подписался на событие `submit` формы:

```
$("#editModalForm").submit(() =>
{
    let list = $('#editPropertiesTable > tbody').prop("childNodes");

    let keyValuePair = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        let firstCell = list[i].cells[0];
        let secondCell = list[i].cells[1];

        let key = $(firstCell).prop('innerText');
        let  value = $(secondCell).children("input").val();

        keyValuePair.push({ key, value });

        console.log(key, value);
    }

    //Пытаюсь задать input
    $("#JsonKeyValue").val(JSON.stringify(keyValuePair));
});
```

И в моем `OnPostAsync`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    ValidateModel();
    var createUpdate = ObjectMapper.Map<EditShopItemViewModel, CreateUpdateShopItemDto>(EditShopItemVM);
    await _service.UpdateAsync(Id, createUpdate);
    return NoContent();
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что **сначала** вызывается `OnPostAsync`, а только потом событие `submit` и соответственно одно свойство в забинженной модели - null (т.к задаю в последней строчке js кода). Есть ли возможность сначала выполнить submit событие, а только потом уже вызов `OnPostAsync`? Может быть есть какое-нибудь событие before submit или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: В документации [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) написано, что это событие происходит "prior to the actual submission" - **до** отправки формы. И её даже можно отменить.

Comment: Чаще используйте `const` вместо `let` там где возможно, код проще читать будет. И вот это еще https://learn.javascript.ru/map-set

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тогда почему у меня вызывается сначала OnPostAsync, а затем уже submit? У меня даже preventDefault не отменяет событие

Comment: Пока не могу сказать, надо подумать

Comment: На странице несколько форм? Может, событие навешано на одну, а отправляется другая...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov форма одна

Comment: посмотрите в сторону EditForm https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0